# Anonymous Object Type

Tags: c#

I have 2 function in C#:

```
function A (){
   var arrDataList = new[] { new { dlName = dlFashion, idCate = 1 }, new { dlName = dlSport, idCate = 2 }, new { dlName = dlElec, idCate = 3 } };
   B(arrDataList);
}

function B(Array a){
   var arrDataList = a;
   foreach (var item in arrDataList)
        {
            item.dlName.DataSource = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client().GetProductBestSeller(item.idCate); // throw error
            item.dlName.DataBind(); // throw error
        }
}
```

How to function B see the arrDataList in function A.

Comment: Instead of using an anonymous type, create a private class with those properties in them `private class MyProducts { public string idCate {get;set];  (other properties here) }` and pass an array of those to your function `B(MyProducts[] a)`

Comment: Is the problem that you want to pass the object anonymously instead of as the declared parameter type `Array`?

Comment: You know there are no "fuctions" in C# but methods? So your code won´t even compile. However do you want to pass the list of anonymous objects to the method `B`? Then you may use the keyword `dynamic` within `B`s siganture.

Comment: @thanhnamtrần this is not C# Code.. what are you trying to do.. why not do some googling and read up on some free online C# for beginner Tutorials

Comment: If you wanted to trick people into converting your pseudo-code into C#, you just did it...

Comment: I know that is not C# code, I am the example for everyone to understand what I need to ask. !!!

Answer (score 2):

As anonymous objects only inherit from `object` you caonnot maintain the type-information. However you may use `dynamic`:

```
void B(dynamic[] a){
   var arrDataList = a;
   foreach (var item in arrDataList)
   {
       item.dlName.DataSource = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client().GetProductBestSeller(item.idCate); // throw error
       item.dlName.DataBind(); // throw error
   }
}
```

However there is no compile-time type-check so if your objects within your array do NOT implment the properties you notice it only at runtime. This this approach is highly not recommended. You´d better be off creating actual types and a method expecting these types.

Comment: I prefer to avoid dynamic as much as possible, but it does validly answer the question

Comment: @Grax Me too, I added a notice therefor.